# WPF. not closed wpf application from another application (servise)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have wpf and console application. 
I want correctly close wpf application from another app.

Code closing application:

```
public static async Task CloseProcessAsync(string processName) {
  await Task.Run(() => {
                         try {
                                foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)) { 
                                  process.Close(); 
                                }
                              } catch (Exception e) {
                                Logger.Error($"Utils.utils.FileUtils.{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}: {e.Message}");
                              }
                        });
}
```

Сlosure processing code:

```
    private void MainWindow_OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
        Logger.Debug(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name); 
    }

    private void MainWindow_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
        Logger.Debug(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }
```

The problem is that the methods Close() \ Dispose() \ CloseMainWindow() do not work on the wpf app.  Logs is empty

I tried to solve the problem as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295931/how-to-close-a-wpf-application-running-in-system-tray-from-a-c-sharp-console-app). But in my case, the CloseMainWindow() method does not work even when the GUI of the WPF app opened.

As I understand it, I need a special to handle the closing request in  wpf app, rather than just overriding the methods MainWindow_OnClosing() or MainWindow_OnClosed().

I think the solution should be very simple, without using third-party libraries.

Comment: Good question, but I cannot figure out how the "violent" code about closing a process is somewhat related to closing a window...

Comment: @JB, I want to update my application with svn. To do this, I launch a console application that closes my wpf application, performs an update and launches the application back.
The process.Kill () method does everything I need, but there is a problem! I need to free all resources when closing wpf, and kill () does not do this.
+ remains  icon in tray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("WPFProcName").First();
proc.CloseMainWindow();
```

Does the job and both `App.Exit` and `Window.Closed` being called.
Check the process is found(you use the right name). Also you can try to start the console with admin permission.

Comment: Thanks! Administrator rights really solve my problem, and everything works out! But this is very strange, and I will have to look for ways to launch a console application with administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows taskkill command:

```
var yourWpfProcessName= "";
var taskKillProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo($"taskkill /im {yourWpfProcessName}");
var taskKillProcess = Process.Start(taskKillProcessInfo);
 taskKillProcess .WaitForExit();
if(taskKillProcess.ExitCode==0)
    //success
```

Then hook up to the Exit event of the Application object to clean up resources:

```
// in App.Xaml
protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
{ 
//clean up resources   
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, OnExit () is not called for me.

Answer (score 0):

Answering with your particular comment in mind :

Instead of killing your own process, send him a signal. For example with a named Event (maybe the class `EventWaitHandle`).

The main process `Wait()` on the named event, and it will shutdown properly when signalled, and the killer/updater `Set()` the event.